# Use External monitor instead of faulty laptop monitor

Tags: external-monitor

My laptop monitor is faulty and I am planning to use it as a 'desktop'. I bought an external led monitor. But when I connect it to my laptop via HDMI, the desktop gets extended. What I really want is to turn off the display on my laptop and use the external monitor, not dual monitor. How to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

System->Preferences->monitors

Select the screen labelled laptop (or similar), select the "off" radio button and then click apply. That worked for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a key, which pressed in combination with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, will turn off your laptop monitor. That key is usually on the function keys. What is your laptop model?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use disper: [see my answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31309/how-to-customise-one-session-for-dual-monitors-and-another-for-single-monitors)