# Using External Monitor with Laptop Monitor as separate monitors

Tags: nvidia, external-monitor

I am trying to use 32"LCD monitor with my ubuntu 10.10 installation. I am trying to use my laptop screen and external monitor at the same time but having two separate desktops. I also want to use my laptop with 1280x800 resolution and external one with 1920 x 1080 using VGA.

However, ubuntu sees my external LCD as a CRT and provide 13....x... resolution at the best not above.

My graphics card driver is Nvidia 270.... driver.

Is ubuntu capable of using two monitors separately or should i give up?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to install a tool called disper. It's a command line tool focused on NVIDIA-drivers, because they don't support xrandr.

Info: [Disper homepage](http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/)

Installation: [PPA for Disper on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~disper-dev/+archive/ppa)

You can also look at my answer to a similar question. There are some example scripts i use with disper:
[Switching Monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31309/how-to-customise-one-session-for-dual-monitors-and-another-for-single-monitors/32496#32496)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu does support multiple monitor configurations.  You should be able to configure how things are displayed from the `Monitors` control panel (under `System -> Preferences`).

If you are using the proprietary Nvidia driver, you might need to use the Nvidia specific settings tool instead.